# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on EC_GROUP_get_curve_name BoringSSL on iOS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, exc-bad-access, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, boringssl

I am not sure if anyone has encounter this when trying to integrate google cloud speech in their ios projects. I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on EC_GROUP_get_curve_name in BoringSSL.

In my project, in order to get it to compile, I had to [redefine](http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/) symbols in Other C flags since I had another library using openSSL that is being used as well in another library.

Here is the call stack for the crash whenever I do a gRPC call:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
After digging a bit deeper, I noticed that when it tries to retrieves the EC_GROUP in ec_key.c, the key value is completely different than what it's been passed in from SSL_CTX_set_temp_ecdh (ssl_lib.c). The reference to group is no longer there when it tries to retrieve the group.

Comment: Could you set watchpoint to find out when and why the key was modified?

Comment: Also there are some sample projects of Google speech API in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples. Maybe that would be helpful.

Comment: my integration is based off that those samples. The only difference is that in my project I have another library that is using openSSL that's causing problems for me.

Comment: I got this from boringssl team that a crash is expected when linking boringssl and openssl into the same binary and using objects of each other. They seem to have a quite involved way to make this work. You might want to post this question on their mailing list.

Comment: manage to resolve this, we had to build a dynamic embedded framwork just for ios and expose the headers we needed in there. not an easy task to do.